# Imported FBX Upside Down textures and materials in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, fbx

I'm Trying transfer my created scene in Autodesk 3DS MAX 2019 to Unity 2018. I've tried 2 ways. firs:import directly the .max file to ma assests. and the second: Export and .FBX file from 3ds max and then import the .FBX to Unity. both ways made me a problem. some of textures and materials in unity are upside down!!! I tried to scale them to a negative content but it is not working. because only some parts of and object are upside down and i don't want to rotate the whole object. and negative amount of scale rotates only material Not the texture. for example my stairs to upper floor now are stairs to a ramp(upside down).Can anyone help me to fix this ? **Screen shots uploaded.**

[Top View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPQQs.jpg)

[Bottom View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdx1m.jpg)

[3DS MAX View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVXjc.jpg)

Is there anyway that I can import the model correctly textured. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I never used autodesk but for me it looks like the normales are not flipped the right way. Here is the [documentation](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/alias-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Alias-Modeling/files/GUID-81804C90-9343-4CD2-9E3F-CAFDA5070B30-htm.html) from autodesk.